# How can I shift my UIScrollView down in order to have a picture at the top of my view outside of the ScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am attempting to use a UIScrollView in order to create a scrollView that is shifted down in my view controller. I am using xib files to create the scrollview and would like to add the scrollview to my view shifted down a portion of the view screen.

Here is the code I'm using to add the scrollview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setLabelsAndPicture];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    // then set frame to be the size of the view's frame
    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;

    // now add our scroll view to the main view
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: Change the scroll view's `frame` as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculate your starting y point and new height to accommodate for the imageView
side note you'd should probably be using auto layout

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setLabelsAndPicture];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    // then set frame to be the size of the view's frame
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,YourImageView.bounds.size.Height, 
                                       self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                                       self.view.bounds.size.height - 
                                       YourImageView.bounds.size.Height );
    // <<< calculate your starting y point and new height to accommodate for the imageView

    // now add our scroll view to the main view
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```